# DocuSign Metadata - Bulk Update Add envelope custom fields

Tags: docusignapi

Our DocuSign templates appear to have hardcoded custom Metadata fields, for example when i create a new template it has "Patch number and Region" under a "Add envelope custom fields" section.

Is there a way to bulk update this for a large number of templates or remove it for those specific ones.

I would like to do this via PowerShell and have already used a script that bulk creates templates however when I added 'CustomField' section it did freeze the bulk import so now that i have those i would now like to update that section of the template to N/A under Patch and South under Region for all.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because you have account custom fields set up.

You can read more about them from here:

[Envelope Custom fields](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=qor1583277385137.html&_LANG=enus)

[Track your envelopes with custom fields Article](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-track-your-templates-envelope-custom-fields)

[EnvelopeCustomFields API Resource](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopecustomfields/)

[Create and Manage DocuSign Custom Fields](https://berkeley.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sys_kb_id=8f8a6e58db7f54506fe8ac1b1396193d&sysparm_nameofstack=&sysparm_kb_search_table=)